# Sending value to input not working - python webscraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am currently scraping website https://glasschain.org (to be precise let's focus on example - https://glasschain.org/btc/wallet/100478015). There is a tab named 'Addresses', when I want to go to the X-th page (in this example equals 5 000) from available over 12 000 (to parallel some operations and not do it iteratively). To do it manually, I need to click on ... button and write a number and click ENTER. I use Python and selenium library to do it automatically and I have managed with clicking the button but I can't send a value to a field which appears after my click (in source code of website after clicking to button there is no new input field where I can send that value so I have tried to send it to the only existing element - earlier clicked button). Can anyone help me with that ? :)

My code:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://glasschain.org/btc/wallet/100478015')
time.sleep(5)
adr_button = driver.find_elements_by_id('tab-Addresses')[1]
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", adr_button)
time.sleep(5)
dots_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ellipse')[0]
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", dots_button)
dots_button.send_keys(5000)
```

My error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.77)`

Version of selenium I am working with: 3.141.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your specific version of `selenium`, but here's a solution that works with a more recent version, `selenium 4.7.2`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from time import sleep


s = Service('bin/chromedriver.exe')

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://glasschain.org/btc/wallet/100478015')
delay = 3  # seconds
try:
    adr_button = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'tab-Addresses')))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading timed out, exiting...")
    exit()

# click the GDPR cookies accept button, if that hasn't happened yet
gdpr_button = driver.find_element(by='id', value='gdpr')
if gdpr_button:
    driver.execute_script("gdpr('accept');")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", adr_button)

try:
    dots_button = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ellipse')))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading timed out, exiting...")
    exit()

# click the dots button, to make the input appear
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", dots_button)

# select the input, modify the value and then make it lose focus
dots_input = dots_button.find_element('xpath', "//span[@class='ellipse clickable']/input")
print(dots_input)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','5000');", dots_input)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].blur();", dots_input)

# just so you can see before the driver closes the browser again
sleep(10)
```

Note that, instead of waiting a number of seconds, the script simply waits until a specific element is loaded and then continues. There's still a `delay` defined, but this is now the maximum amount of time the script will wait for the element to load, instead of just waiting a fixed amount of time.

Once the button is clicked, a nested `input` element appears, which is selected and then JavaScript is executed to change its value and cause it to lose focus (blur), so that the new value gets applied.

(note that I have the Chrome driver in a subfolder next to the script, called `bin`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I rewrote it to my current version of selenium (small details only changes) and it works as expected. :)

Comment: That's great, you're welcome. If you feel your question has been answered, consider clicking the checkmark next to the answer, so that your question no longer appears as unanswered.